# unity градус поворота в vector2 (2 значения от -1,1)

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Physics2D.Raycast принимает vector2 для обозначения направления, где вверх - 0,1, вниз 0, -1, вправо 1, 0, и в лево -1, 0
Как я могу преобразовать transform.Rotation.z в Vector2, для того, чтобы луч смотрел туда же, куда и объект, Vector2.down всегда будет пускать луч вниз, независимо от поворота объекта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если `Fi=transform.Rotation.z` означает угол поворота вокруг оси Z, то

```
Vector2.x = cos(Fi)
Vector2.y = sin(Fi)
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает, при 90 градусах поворота по z. луч поворачивается всего на 45, на 180 градусах луч примерно на 70
вот мой код
Vector2 correct = Vector2.zero;
            correct.x = Mathf.Cos(transform.rotation.z);
            correct.y = Mathf.Sin(transform.rotation.z);
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, correct, color: Color.blue, 1);

Comment: У вас углы в градусах или в радианах? Mathf.Cos нужны радианы

Comment: углы это transform.rotation.z, значения от -1, до 1

Comment: у, так transform.Rotation - это кватернион, его z не описывает положение или вращение, это один компонент вектора оси. Тогда мой ответ не в тему.

Comment: ааа, спасибо вам огромное, получилось, щас дополню вопрос, что-бы люди могли найти ответ на такой вопрос

Answer (score 2):

```
// перевод градуса в радиану
float radian = transform.Rotation.z*Mathf.Deg2Rad;
Vector2 vector = new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(radian), Mathf.Sin(radian));
```

Не зная геометрии окружности далеко в геймдеве не уедешь. Что такое `Sin`, `Cos` и `Pi` нужно знать.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Vector2 correct = Vector2.zero;
 correct.x = Mathf.Cos(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
 correct.y = Mathf.Sin(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z * Mathf.Deg2Rad);  
 Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, correct, color: Color.blue, 1);
```

данный код работает